# Form new dataframes from list by combining similar entries in all dataframes

Tags: r, list, lapply, cbind

I have a list with many dataframes (example provided below).

```
    G100=structure(list(Return.Period = structure(c(4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
        1L), .Label = c("100yrs", "10yrs", "20yrs", "2yrs", "50yrs", 
        "5yrs"), class = "factor"), X95..lower.CI = c(54.3488053692529, 
        73.33363378538, 84.0868168935697, 91.6191228597281, 96.3360349026068, 
        95.4278817251266), Estimate = c(61.6857930414643, 84.8210149260708, 
        101.483909733627, 118.735593472652, 143.33257990536, 163.806035490329
        ), X95..upper.CI = c(69.0227807136758, 96.3083960667617, 118.881002573685, 
        145.852064085577, 190.329124908114, 232.18418925553)), .Names = c("Return.Period", 
        "X95..lower.CI", "Estimate", "X95..upper.CI"), row.names = c(NA, 
        -6L), class = "data.frame")

G101<-G100 # just for illustration

mylist=list(G100,G101) # there 100 of these with differet codes
```

names(mylist) represents "SITE". From each dataframe, I would like to take "Estimate" and form a new dataframe which looks like this (not exact because values are not the same for all dfs):
Estimate`<-`

```
SITE    X2yrs    X5yrs   X10yrs   X20yrs   X50yrs X100yrs
G100 61.68579 84.82101 101.4839 118.7356 143.3326 163.806
G101 61.68579 84.82101 101.4839 118.7356 143.3326 163.806
```

Note that `SITE` is same as dataframe names in `mylist`.

Do the same for `"X95..lower.CI"` and `"X95..upper.CI"`.

So, I will end up with 3 dataframes `"Estimate"`,`"X95..lower.CI"`and`"X95..upper.CI".` with the above layout.

```
#lapply, rbindlist,cbind and others can do but how?
```

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a for loop to add the names. There's probably a fancy `*apply` way, but `for` is easy to use, remember, and understand.

#### Start by adding names:

```
names(mylist) = paste0("G", seq(from = 100, by = 1, length.out = length(mylist)))
```

#### Add `SITE` column as before:

```
for (i in seq_along(mylist)) {
    mylist[[i]]$SITE = names(mylist)[i]
}
```

#### Combine data frames:

Since you have a lot of data frames or they're rather large, use `dplyr::rbind_all` for speed. (In base R, `do.call(rbind, mylist)` would work, but be slower.)

```
library(dplyr)
combined = bind_rows(mylist)
```

(Older versions of `dplyr` can use `rbind_all` instead of `bind_rows`, but this will soon be deprecated: (https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/803).)

#### Transform the Estimate and CI columns from long to wide.

This is easy with `tidyr`, though `reshape2::dcast` works similarly:

```
library(tidyr)
Estimate = combined %>% select(SITE, Return.Period, Estimate) %>%
    spread(key = Return.Period, value = Estimate)
head(Estimate)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 7]
#
#   SITE  100yrs    10yrs    20yrs     2yrs    50yrs     5yrs
# 1 G100 163.806 101.4839 118.7356 61.68579 143.3326 84.82101
# 2 G101 163.806 101.4839 118.7356 61.68579 143.3326 84.82101    

Lower95 = combined %>% select(SITE, Return.Period, X95..lower.CI) %>%
    spread(key = Return.Period, value = X95..lower.CI)
head(Lower95)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 7]
#
#   SITE   100yrs    10yrs    20yrs     2yrs    50yrs     5yrs
# 1 G100 95.42788 84.08682 91.61912 54.34881 96.33603 73.33363
# 2 G101 95.42788 84.08682 91.61912 54.34881 96.33603 73.33363
```

You might want to reorder the columns un-alphabetically.

> Do the same for ``"X95..upper.CI"`.

Still left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: if I use the loop above on `mylist`, the dataframes will be labled as [[1]] and [[2]] but I want [[G100]] and [[G101]]. Remeber I have >100 such files. Secondly, do not just combine the dataframes as you suggest but "Estimate","X95..lower.CI" and "X95..upper.CI"  FINAL dataframes should be as arranged above. Basically, I would like to go to each dataframe, and for `"Estimate"`, extract `X2yrs    X5yrs   X10yrs   X20yrs   X50yrs X100yrs` and form a table as shown above. Do the same for `"X95..lower.CI" and "X95..upper.CI"`. My result will be 3 dataframes.